# Is L2TP as secure as IPSEC for VPNs?

Tags: network, ipsec, protocols, vpn

Is it as secure to use L2TP for VPN access, rather than IPSEC? Am I introducing any risks by using L2TP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L2TP does not provide any confidentiality or authentication. A common setup is using L2TP along with IPSEC (see [RFC 3193](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3193)).

**EDIT:** L2TP does provide tunnel end-point authentication. It does not provide encryption and message authentication.

Comment: In almost all cases when someone says "L2TP VPN" they mean L2TP/IPSEC VPN. While it is possible to set up a pure L2TP tunnel it is rarely done in practice.

Comment: Ah yes I guess I did mean L2TP/IPSEC VPN then.